# Show that $ A^t (U^⊥ )=(A^{-1} (U))^⊥ $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V,W be two finite dimensional vector spaces, $A:V→W$ linear  and $U⊆W$

I need to show that $A^t (U^⊥ )=(A^{-1} (U))^⊥$, where $A^t:W→V$ with $(Av,w)=(v,A^t w)$  is the adjoint operator and  $A^{-1} (U)$ is the archetype of $U$.
I have tried to show $(A^{-1} (U))^⊥⊆A^t (U^⊥)$  but I haven’t been able to figure out the other inclusion so far.

I would very much appreciate the help, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go by the definitions and show one inclusion at a time. In order to show "$\subseteq$" let $y\in A^t (U^\perp)$. Then there is some $x\in U^\perp$ such that $y=A^t x$. Now, if $z\in A^{-1}(U)$, then

$(y,z)=(A^t x,z)=(x,Az)=0$, since $Az\in U$ and $x\in U^{\perp}$.

As $z$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that $A^t(U^{\perp})\subseteq (A^{-1}(U))^\perp$.

I leave the converse inclusion for you as an exercise.